# Sum 1 to a value by clicking an image - PHP

Tags: javascript, php, session, get

I guys, I need yo help for this. I have this code, wich shows me the products I have in my shopping cart:

```
for($i=0;$i<count($_SESSION['productos']);$i++)
{
    $id = $_SESSION['productos'][$i];
    $prods = mysql_query('SELECT * from productos where idprod='.$id.'');
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($prods);
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['nombre']; echo "</td>";

        if($_GET[action]=="suma")
        {
         $_SESSION['unidades'][$i] =  $_SESSION['unidades'][$i] + 1;
        }
        elseif($_GET[action]=="resta")
        {
        $_SESSION['unidades'][$i] =  $_SESSION['unidades'][$i] - 1;
        }

        echo "<td><input name=".$i." type='text' value=" . $_SESSION['unidades'][$i]; echo " size='5'/></td>";  
        echo "<td><a href='carro_detalle.php?action=suma'><img src='images/flecharriba.png' width='10x' height='10px'/></a></td>";
        echo "<td><a href='carro_detalle.php?action=resta'><img src='images/flechabajo.png' width='10px' height='10px'/></a></td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['precio']; echo "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['precio'] * $_SESSION['unidades'][$i]; echo "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
}
```

I need to sum 1 unity or rest 1 unity to $_SESSION['unidades'][$i] just to the selected product, when I click the two images respectively.
The thing is that when I click, it adds me 1 to all the products. Any easy way of doing this without using $_GET vars? I dont have high knowledge about JavasScript.
Thanks!!

Comment: if you don't want all the products to be updated, then you shouldn't be doing a `for()` loop on everything in the shopping cart.

Comment: @MarcB Then, how do I loop the session array where I store all the selected products?

Comment: use the product ID  as cart key, not some random/sequential int. `$_SESSION['cart'][$prod_id]['quantity']++` is var easier than having to loop over the whole cart to find whatever you want to update.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: @tyteen4a03 Ok, thanks, I will take a look. Im new at this, and I just use the basic functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably should remove your condition from the loop and put it outside of it:

```
if($_GET[action]=="suma")
{
    $_SESSION['unidades'][$i] =  $_SESSION['unidades'][$i] + 1;
}
elseif($_GET[action]=="resta")
{
    $_SESSION['unidades'][$i] =  $_SESSION['unidades'][$i] - 1;
}


for($i=0;$i<count($_SESSION['productos']);$i++)
{
$id = $_SESSION['productos'][$i];
$prods = mysql_query('SELECT * from productos where idprod='.$id.'');
$row = mysql_fetch_array($prods);
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['nombre']; echo "</td>";

    echo "<td><input name=".$i." type='text' value=" . $_SESSION['unidades'][$i]; echo " size='5'/></td>";  
    echo "<td><a href='carro_detalle.php?action=suma'><img src='images/flecharriba.png' width='10x' height='10px'/></a></td>";
    echo "<td><a href='carro_detalle.php?action=resta'><img src='images/flechabajo.png' width='10px' height='10px'/></a></td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['precio']; echo "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['precio'] * $_SESSION['unidades'][$i]; echo "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
}
```

Comment: You give me an idea, but thats not possible because I need the variable $i of the loop for(). Thanks anyway ;)